# Set class on Parent and Sub-Menu in Laravel Bade View

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I want to set `m-menu__item--open` class on parent menu `<li>` and `m-menu__item--active` class on sub-menu item `<li>` in my Laravel bade based on current page. Below is the `HTML` extracted from the bade template.

```
<li class="m-menu__item m-menu__item--open" aria-haspopup="true" m-menu-submenu-toggle="hover">
    <a href="javascript:;" class="m-menu__link m-menu__toggle">
        <i class="m-menu__link-icon flaticon-layers"></i>
        <span class="m-menu__link-text">FAQ</span>
        <i class="m-menu__ver-arrow la la-angle-right"></i>
    </a>
    <div class="m-menu__submenu " m-hidden-height="840">
        <span class="m-menu__arrow"></span>
        <ul class="m-menu__subnav">
            <li class="m-menu__item  m-menu__item--active" aria-haspopup="true">
                <a href="{{ url('/') }}/admin/faq/list/1" class="m-menu__link ">
                    <i class="m-menu__link-bullet m-menu__link-bullet--dot">
                        <span></span>
                    </i>
                    <span class="m-menu__link-text">English</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="m-menu__item  m-menu__item" aria-haspopup="true">
                <a href="{{ url('/') }}/admin/faq/list/2" class="m-menu__link ">
                    <i class="m-menu__link-bullet m-menu__link-bullet--dot">
                        <span></span>
                    </i>
                    <span class="m-menu__link-text">Korean</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="m-menu__item  m-menu__item" aria-haspopup="true">
                <a href="{{ url('/') }}/admin/faq/list/3" class="m-menu__link ">
                    <i class="m-menu__link-bullet m-menu__link-bullet--dot">
                        <span></span>
                    </i>
                    <span class="m-menu__link-text">Chinese</span>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as I understand, you want to change your menu classes by the current url..

laravel has `is()` method in Request class. You may want to use it.

```
class="{{Request::is('category/products') ? 'm-menu__item--active' : 'm-menu__item--open'}}"
```

if your current url `base-url/category/products` then you're gonna get the 'm-menu__item--active' class